# Track stolen unopened Huawei phone

Tags: huawei, gps-tracking, imei

My friends sended me a brand new Huawei phone from country A to country B. After waiting 4 weeks the local post told me that my packages was stolen.

Now my girlfriend proposed me to check if it's possible to track a huawei phone or to check atleast if it has been activated?

I know with IPhones you can check before you buy them if they are activated or not. But with Huawei phones? My friends took a picture of the IMEI of the backside of the phone. And we still have the bill of the phone

Comment: What prevents you from taking the issue to the company that sold it or the service that went with it?

Comment: Nothing, I just would like to know if I can check from home if it has been activated.